# iBooks library empty after upgrade

Tags: applications

Since upgrading my iPad all the books are gone from my library yet when I go to iTunes it shows the books I purchased. Am I going to have to download them again?

Comment: In iTunes, disable syncing of books, do a sync, and then re-enable.  Maybe it is a bit confused?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen if you're a bit premature unplugging your iPad from iTunes.  Try plugging it in and resyncing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't have any backup app like pkgbackup, you can still reload them from iTunes if you bought them.